# Unexpected behaviour of SelectedValueChange event when loading combobox with data from EntityDataModel in C# winforms application

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I'm using Windows Forms C# application for loading data in combobox using linq to entity

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyEntityDataModel db = new MyEntityDataModel();
            var q = from a in db.Customers orderby a.CustomerID descending select new { ID = a.CustomerID, Name = a.Name.Trim() };
            comboBox1.DataSource = q.ToList();
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
        }
        private void comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
        }
```

When running code , on Loading data for first time , selected value change fire 4 events for the 4 customers listed , but all are fired for Customer4 only ; 2 of them load display member as full data row while the other 2 load selected value correctly

[image]

1) How to prevent Selected value change event from showing full data row and show Selected value only in the first items ?
2) Why all events are fired only for first item (Customer4) ?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: 1) How to prevent Selected value change event from showing full data row and show Selected value only in the first items ?
2) Why all events are fired only for Item number 4 ?

Comment: If the event raises 3 times, it's OK. It's raising for the first item of list 3 times, first time for setting `DataSource`, second time for setting `ValueMember` member and third time `DisplayMember`.

Comment: Also your log should show `Name` of customer for the 3rd event. But probably the screenshot is for another execution.

Comment: If i link a certain method for the selectedvalue change event, how to ensure that Value member loaded correctly before firing action

Comment: It's not clear what's your requirement exactly, but you can remove the handler before setting data source and add it again after finishing settings: `comboBox1.SelectedValueChanged-=new comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged; /*. . .*/ comboBox1.SelectedValueChanged+=new comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged;`

Comment: Thanks alot. That solved my issue. Please post it as answer. Thanks, again

Comment: You're welcome and thanks for the kind offer, The Ivan's answer is good enough, you can mark it as accepted :)

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thanks for the kind words and sportsmanship! I was also considering that option, but decided that it's too brute force :) And of course it applies generally to any event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event fires only for the selected item, which in your case is the first item (Customer4). The number of times event fires has nothing to do with number of the items in the list, but the number of data binding related property assignments you do. In your case, it fires when you assign `DataSource` (1), then when you assign `ValueMember` (2 times - one before setting the property and one after) and finally when you set `DisplayMember` (1), so totally 4 times.

I would agree that it's not so intelligent, but note that data binding can work without one or both of the `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` being set, producing different behavior. So they decided to fire that event when any **potentially** affecting property is modified.

So there is no way to make it fire just once. But it can be reduced to 2 calls by assigning `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` **before** `DataSource` (I always use this as rule of thumb):

```
comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
comboBox1.DataSource = q.ToList();
```

Also you should add a check for `SelectedValue` being `null` in order to avoid `NullReferenceException` (which is good in general because it can happen not only in data binding scenarios):

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedValue != null)
        listBox1.Items.Add(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot for the intelligent and clear answer